# Bootstrap 4 column layout alignment issue - nested columns wrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have written the below column layout in Bootstrap 4. It is not aligned properly. The last of the nested columns breaks to a new line.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label class="col-form-label custom-label" for="idNo">Lable Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <label class="col-form-label">:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <label class="col-form-label">Label Value</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
  </div>[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: make first column 9, and the other one 3.

Comment: but my my requirement is first 3 then 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough width in the `col-sm-3` to fit the content and padding of the 3 columns so the columns wrap (stack vertically). To prevent this, you can adjust the padding on the columns inside the row. Bootstrap 4 has a `no-gutters` class for this purpose...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label class="col-form-label custom-label" for="idNo">Lable Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <label class="col-form-label">:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Label Value</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/WBZZpqvuvC

Bootstrap 4 also has [padding utility classes classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) that can be used to adjust padding on individual columns which is another option that may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <label class="col-form-label custom-label" for="idNo">Lable Name</label>
            </li>
           <li class="list-inline-item">
                <label class="col-form-label">:</label>
            </li>
           <li class="list-inline-item">
                <label class="col-form-label">Label Value</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9"></div>
</div>
```